Unable to Create Directory in Azure File Share Using Managed Identity with Node.js
I'm using a managed identity to create and manage resources in an Azure Storage account. I've successfully created a file share without using an account key, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to create a directory within that file share.
I have turned on identity from the VM(where I am running the node script) also I have given appropriate permission.
Here is the error message I'm receiving:
RestError: An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.
RequestId:[REDACTED]
Time:2024-12-31T07:42:57.4819576Z
{
  "name": "RestError",
  "code": "MissingRequiredHeader",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "details": {
    "errorCode": "MissingRequiredHeader",
    "content-length": "305",
    "content-type": "application/xml",
    "server": "Windows-Azure-File/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
    "x-ms-request-id": "[REDACTED]",
    "x-ms-client-request-id": "[REDACTED]",
    "x-ms-version": "2025-01-05",
    "date": "Tue, 31 Dec 2024 07:42:56 GMT",
    "message": "An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\nRequestId:[REDACTED]\nTime:2024-12-31T07:42:57.4819576Z",
    "code": "MissingRequiredHeader",
    "HeaderName": "x-ms-file-request-intent"
  },
  "request": {
    "url": "https://[STORAGE-ACCOUNT].file.core.windows.net/[FILE-SHARE]/[DIRECTORY]?restype=REDACTED",
    "headers": {
      "x-ms-version": "REDACTED",
      "accept": "application/xml",
      "x-ms-file-permission": "REDACTED",
      "x-ms-file-attributes": "REDACTED",
      "x-ms-file-creation-time": "REDACTED",
      "x-ms-file-last-write-time": "REDACTED",
      "user-agent": "azsdk-js-azure-storage-blob/12.26.0 core-rest-pipeline/1.18.1 Node/20.5.1 OS/(x64-Linux-6.5.0-1025-azure)",
      "x-ms-client-request-id": "[REDACTED]",
      "authorization": "REDACTED"
    },
    "method": "PUT"
  }
}


Here's the Node.jscode I used:
`const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { ShareServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-file-share");

const storageAccountName = "[STORAGE-ACCOUNT]";
const fileShareName = "[FILE-SHARE]";
const directoryName = "[DIRECTORY]";

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

async function main() {
    const serviceClient = new ShareServiceClient(
        `https://${storageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net`,
        credential
    );

    const shareClient = serviceClient.getShareClient(fileShareName);
    const directoryClient = shareClient.getDirectoryClient(directoryName);
    await directoryClient.create();
    console.log(`Directory '${directoryName}' created successfully in file share '${fileShareName}'.`);
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error creating directory:", error);
});
`


Can you help me identify what might be missing or incorrect in my setup?

Could you please share your @azure/storage-file-share package version?

Can you which RBAC role have you used?

do you use a system or user assigned identity?
